# way to speed up Rails loading Backbone Javascript assets on full page load in Dev environment?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

I'm working on a Rails 3.2.6 + Backbone app, and the number of Javascript files served from app/assets/javascripts is at a count of about 91 separate files (there are many sub-views). In a Dev environment, these assets are not bundled up of course, so each is served up by Rails individually (either using WEBrick or Thin) with an expected 304 Not Modified since they're cached.

The problem is: this has begun to be very heavy for a full page reload during development iteration. It's clocking in at about 13 seconds from refresh to the DOM being ready, which is quite bad for rapid development, especially when a lot of JS and CSS is being changed. And I'm pretty sure it's the only real bottleneck as I can watch the Rails log in Terminal, seeing each asset go by, like such:

> Started GET "/assets/views/simple_dialog.js?body=1" for 127.0.0.1 at 2012-11-12 15:39:25 -0800
>   Served asset /views/simple_dialog.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)

Is there anyway to speed up this process? I know there will always be a trade-off, but even if i can get it to 6-7 seconds it'd be a huge improvement. I know Sprockets is supposedly geting many speed boosts in Rails 4, but I'm looking for something in the short-term.

Comment: A 304 should mean that there is no response body sent to the client. It would take a lot of (0ms) in order to add up to 13s.

Comment: yes, haha, i know! but it does indeed take the Rails log about that long to spout out ~100 requests of 0ms in length. as soon as it's done logging them, that's when the page renders.

also, in the Network tab of Chrome i can see all the 304s of the .css and .js, and in the timeline the tooltip bar of each says 'sending' = 0, 'receiving' = ~10ms, and 'dns lookup' = ~4-5ms. still, not enough to account for all the seconds. will investigate further, and try Michael's answer tomorrow. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps try the following:

- In config/environments/development.rb, set `config.assets.debug = false` (see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#turning-debugging-off).  This will cause your files to be joined into a single application.js file, which should reduce load time by not requiring such a large number of separate HTTP requests.
- Try using the [rails-dev-tweaks](https://github.com/wavii/rails-dev-tweaks) gem.  It can help speed up requests to asset files.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your suggestions, Michael. i tried the first one, but unfortunately the [backbone-support gem](https://github.com/thoughtbot/backbone-support) we're using has some things in it that break JS strict mode which I want turned on.  
I've [filed an issue](https://github.com/thoughtbot/backbone-support/issues/9) because the solution, in my opinion, is simple and follows modern best practices.  the bundling (when `config.assets.debug = true`) that occurs must somehow circumvent the strict mode in an expected manner.  
I'll take a look at the rails-dev-tweaks gem soon.

Comment: (sorry for all the micro-edits; was having a hard time with line-breaks in my follow-up comment, so hope you didn't get like a hundred notifications.)